# Python console application design status and interactive

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I have a fixed 2 hr job (four 30 min parts) that I want to kick off from a menu option in a Python console application, and I'm looking for design help.

When a user clicks the menu option to start the job, I want to give some sort of status while the job is running. Maybe show a 30 min countdown for each part.

I'd like to be able to cancel the job through a menu option (and not a keyboard interrupt).

So the interactive part of the program will still allow user to check other menu options while job is running.

My initial questions are below. I know I can research most of these but I want To know if I'm asking myself the right questions.

1. Would the job need to run in the background? If so, how can I cancel something in the background?
2. Best way to initiate to background?
3. Can I show 30 min count down, while still maintaining the interactiveness?

Rough illustration:

```
Running Jobs:
Job 1: 29:30 time left
Interactive console menu:
1. Start Job 1 - started
2. Do other things 
3. Exit
```

Comment: What exactly is this job you mentioned? Is it a python function or something?

Comment: Yes, it's a Python program.

Comment: Another python script or just a function?

Comment: Can be either, which ever is easier or cleaner. Here's what I'm doing. I'm trying to create a Python program on my Raspberry Pi to schedule my sprinklers and do other home automation from console menu. I've thought about a Cron job for the sprinklers but I thought it would be nice to combine it with other small jobs on a console menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The background part is easier. There are many libraries like [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/), [gevent](http://www.gevent.org/) and [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org) that provide event loop support. You can use their event loop to get the job running in the background. There is also library like [schedule](https://github.com/dbader/schedule) to do cron-like job scheduling.

Maintaining interactivness is the hard part. You'll have to use `subprocess` or `threading` to start the job to keep the terminal interactive. And to display the time countdown, you may want to use curses lib like [urwid](http://www.urwid.org/) or [npyscreen](https://code.google.com/p/npyscreen/).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Maybe one day I get to GUI. I've done a little looking around and so far Qt seems like a good framework. Any thoughts?

Comment: Qt is good. It maybe the only GUI lib that has quite excellent performance on almost all platform. And there's python binding like `pyQt` and `pySide`.

Answer (score 1):

I find [npyscreen](http://code.google.com/p/npyscreen/) very helpful for easily creating nice console apps. Look at the [keybindings section](http://npyscreen.readthedocs.org/keybindings.html) to see how key handlers are set up.